# Extend a generic of an interface using psalm

Tags: generics, php-7.4, psalm-php

I'm getting used to use psalm, but I'm facing an issue. I already have this structure in C# and it worked out for me. I didn't really get how I could solve this using psalm.

I have a `ContextInterface` and another implementing it.

```php
interface ContextInterface { public function getProductId(): int; }
interface SingleContextInterface extends ContextInterface { public function getWidth(): int; }
```

Additionally I have strategy interfaces for them.

```php
/**
 * @template-covariant T as ContextInterface
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
interface CalculatorInterface
{
    /**
     * @psalm-param T $context
     */
    public function getPrice(ContextInterface $context): int;
}

/**
 * @template T as SingleContextInterface
 * @template-extends CalculatorInterface<T>
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
interface SingleDimensionalPriceCalculator extends CalculatorInterface { }
```

And one class implementing the interface:

```php
/**
 * @template T as SingleContextInterface
 * @template-implements SingleDimensionalPriceCalculator<T>
 * @psalm-immutable
 */
class SingleDimensionCalculator implements SingleDimensionalPriceCalculator
{
    /**
     * @psalm-param SingleContextInterface $context
     */ 
    public function getPrice(ContextInterface $context): int
    {
        $context->getWidth();
        return 1;
    }
    
}
```

For the `getWidth()` method call I receive the following error:

`ERROR: ImpureMethodCall - 37:19 - Cannot call an possibly-mutating method SingleContextInterface::getWidth from a mutation-free context`

The example on [psalm.dev](https://psalm.dev/r/8bf11cd523)

Of course the real case is more complicated and contains more interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured, the problem was that I marked the template on `CalculatorInterface` as covariant. I can just extend it without, it being covariant.

Example on [psalm.dev](https://psalm.dev/r/9ee8db7801)

Comment: You also dropped `@immutable`, so it's quite natural that you don't get mutability errors anymore

Comment: Adding `@psalm-immutable` on `SingleContextInterface` would fix that as it would mark `getWidth()` as pure.